# Is it possible to convert ACF Flexible Content Layouts into their own Field Groups

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I have been making a page builder using ACF Flexible Content and have made around 16 blocks or components, each with around 7 fields. The caveat to this is that the field saves to one JSON file using `acf/save_json` which was fine, however, some recent merge conflicts have got me thinking about the following.

1. Creating a group for each would be layout inside my Flexible Content field
2. Make said group inactive
3. Use a Clone field in my Flexible Content field to pull in the fields I want

Why?

I was thinking that groups create their own JSON files on save so the only way a developer could have an issue is if they explicitly work on the same component.

Given this, I was wondering if it's possible to programmatically convert what I have into their own groups?